# Recieve raw binary data stream in controller and combine every 2 bytes

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I plan to send raw binary data from a GSM module to a Web API controller.  I'm simulating sending the data with Fiddler.  The data format is 8 bytes eg.

0x18 0x01 0x1B 0x02 0x12 0x10 0x2D 0x0A

[image: Fiddler simulation]

I receive the data at the controller in a 16 byte array:

[image: Data received web API]

the data looks correct:

byte 0 = 49 (Ascii char 1) (binary 0011 0001)

byte 1 = 56 (Ascii char 8) (binary 0011 1000)

I need to combine both these bytes to create a single byte of 0x18 (binary 0001 1000)

Looking at the binary values, it looks like i need to shift byte 0 left 4 places, then use the and operator with byte 1?

I'm a bit stuck if anyone could please help.

Thank you

Comment: You said you are simulating this via fiddler. Are you sure that real application will send binary data like this, and not in real binary form?

Comment: Because what comes in here is actually text (ASCII at least). Looking at it as a `byte[]` adds another conversion layer to the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Using bit operators:

```
    byte a = 49; 
    byte b = 56; 
    a <<= 4;
    b <<= 4;
    b >>= 4;
    byte result = (byte)(b + a);

    Console.WriteLine("{0}", result);
```